# OpenGL When to use Geometry Shaders

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, shader

I currently have a OpenGL sprite drawing class that buffers up a bunch of sprite data then dumps it with glDrawElements. The problem is, creating the sprites that go into the buffer is cumbersome as I have loads of parameters to pass into the buffer with even more redundancy for the shaders. I was wondering if I could reduce CPU load by only loading the buffer with the essentials, location, orientation, texture coordinates etc... and then let a geometry shader turn that nonsense into quads for the fragment shader.

If theres a different answer, I've added the offending method so you can see what I mean:

```
void Machine::draw(key num, BoundingBox loc, float angle){
    SpriteSyncData*    props;
    VertexAttribArray* vdata;
    GLushort*          idata;
    SpriteProperties*  sprite_props;
    int                sliceW;
    int                sliceH;

    sprite_props = &spriteList[num];
    props = &spriteToSync[sprite_props->atlas];

    props->size++;
    if(props->size > props->capacity){
        props->capacity += COARSE_MEM_SCALE;
        props->data   = (VertexAttribArray*) realloc((void*) props->data,   (sizeof(VertexAttribArray)*4) * props->capacity);
        props->i_data = (GLushort*)          realloc((void*) props->i_data, (sizeof(GLushort)*4) * props->capacity);
    }

    vdata = props->data   + (props->size - 1) * 4;
    idata = props->i_data + (props->size - 1) * 4;

    sliceW = sprite_props->location.x1 - sprite_props->location.x0;
    sliceH = sprite_props->location.y1 - sprite_props->location.y0;

    if(sprite_props->flags & DRAW_TILED){
        vdata[0].p = QVector3D(loc.x1, loc.y0, UNIFORM_DEPTH);
        vdata[1].p = QVector3D(loc.x0, loc.y0, UNIFORM_DEPTH);
        vdata[2].p = QVector3D(loc.x0, loc.y1, UNIFORM_DEPTH);
        vdata[3].p = QVector3D(loc.x1, loc.y1, UNIFORM_DEPTH);
        vdata[0].s = QVector2D(((float) (loc.x1 - loc.x0)) / sliceW,
                               ((float) (loc.y1 - loc.y0)) / sliceH);
        vdata[0].r = QVector2D(0, 0);
        vdata[1].r = vdata[0].r;
        vdata[2].r = vdata[0].r;
        vdata[3].r = vdata[0].r;
    }
    else{
        vdata[0].p = QVector3D(loc.x0 + sliceW, loc.y0,          UNIFORM_DEPTH);
        vdata[1].p = QVector3D(loc.x0,          loc.y0,          UNIFORM_DEPTH);
        vdata[2].p = QVector3D(loc.x0,          loc.y0 + sliceH, UNIFORM_DEPTH);
        vdata[3].p = QVector3D(loc.x0 + sliceW, loc.y0 + sliceH, UNIFORM_DEPTH);
        vdata[0].s = QVector2D(1, 1);
        vdata[0].r = QVector2D(sliceW, sliceH);
        vdata[1].r = vdata[0].r;
        vdata[2].r = vdata[0].r;
        vdata[3].r = vdata[0].r;
    }
    vdata[0].t = QVector2D(sprite_props->texCoords[2], sprite_props->texCoords[1]);
    vdata[1].t = QVector2D(sprite_props->texCoords[0], sprite_props->texCoords[1]);
    vdata[2].t = QVector2D(sprite_props->texCoords[0], sprite_props->texCoords[3]);
    vdata[3].t = QVector2D(sprite_props->texCoords[2], sprite_props->texCoords[3]);
    vdata[1].s = vdata[0].s;
    vdata[2].s = vdata[0].s;
    vdata[3].s = vdata[0].s;

    vdata[0].s_lo = QVector2D(sprite_props->texCoords[0], sprite_props->texCoords[1]);
    vdata[0].s_hi = QVector2D(sprite_props->texCoords[2] - sprite_props->texCoords[0],
                              sprite_props->texCoords[3] - sprite_props->texCoords[1]);
    vdata[1].s_lo = vdata[0].s_lo;
    vdata[1].s_hi = vdata[0].s_hi;
    vdata[2].s_lo = vdata[0].s_lo;
    vdata[2].s_hi = vdata[0].s_hi;
    vdata[3].s_lo = vdata[0].s_lo;
    vdata[3].s_hi = vdata[0].s_hi;

    vdata[0].o = (vdata[1].p + vdata[3].p) * 0.5;
    vdata[1].o = vdata[0].o;
    vdata[2].o = vdata[0].o;
    vdata[3].o = vdata[0].o;

    vdata[0].a = angle;
    vdata[1].a = angle;
    vdata[2].a = angle;
    vdata[3].a = angle;

    idata[0] = (props->size - 1) * 4;
    idata[1] = idata[0] + 1;
    idata[2] = idata[0] + 2;
    idata[3] = idata[0] + 3;

}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but generally, use geometry shader only if you have to (there is no other way how to do what you want). If you use geometry shader only for some optimization, it'll almost always be counterproductive.

Comment: Why is this so? Isn't it generally always better to push any parallel workload onto the GPU? (in this case, generating all of the vertex data)

Comment: GS is not so parallel as the other parts of pipeline, and there are some other problems. Of course it depends, but generally it's better to avoid it. Check this http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/48434

Comment: Oh okay. So is there no better way to generate this type of data then by-frame push it onto a vertex buffer then render it? I ask because I tried amping the sprite count up to 10,000 and already saw slowdowns and I'm suspicious its all of the overhead from the cpu generating redundant vertex data and handing it to a vbo.